# Infared: some controllers send code into infinite loop

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, loop, infrared

I have a piece of code that captures input from infrared and spits it out to the serial port.

When I use it with a simple controller that comes with a typical kit, it receives the infrared code just fine for each button I depress.

But when I try and capture information from my air conditioning remote (the one I need to clone), I receive the first hexcode and then the output gets thrown into an infinite loop with that 1 hexcode, and will not break out.

```cpp
#include <IRremote.h>
    
const int RECV_PIN = 7;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;
    
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  irrecv.enableIRIn();
  irrecv.blink13(true);
}
    
void loop(){
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    irrecv.resume();
  }
}
```

What is causing the infinite loop from "some" controllers and how do I prevent it?

Update:

In changelog they say they renamed RAW_BUF to RAW_BUFFER_LENGTH. I find RAW_BUFFER_LENGTH in IRremoteInt.h and not IRremote.h

I'm not calling on IRremoteInt.h

I did try and reset the buffer from 101 to 201 in IRremoteInt.h, recompiled, uploaded, same issue.

Comment: some air conditioners have really long bit sequences ... they can also use error checking

Comment: @jsotola That sounds very plausible. How do I capter all of it?

Comment: @jsotola  Quilo model QP114

Comment: try this to capture all of the bit stream ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751255/how-to-correctly-receive-and-send-raw-ir-data-from-arduino

Comment: @jsotola The code from that page performs a much more robust infinite loop, but still the same infinite loop. In the answers they mention #define RAWBUF 100. That does not exist in my IRremote.h

Comment: i wonder if you are on the wrong track ... your sketch is an infinite loop ... basically, all arduino sketches are infinite loops

Comment: @jsotola so, you're saying that 10 million lines (and counting, very quickly) of https://i.imgur.com/3VU4t39.png is sane? 
No, it is not because of the main program loop.